# Custom profile only displaying one result in search

Tags: profile, search, search-results

[image: Screenshot of search results page, showing only a single result even though the description says 1-50 of 775]

I've been trying to build a profile to customise the columns shown in search results.

I have the profile working, showing the columns I wanted, but for some reason the results page is only displaying one per page. As shown in the screenshot, it should be displaying 50 results per page. And it's not possible to move though the results one at a time, either. the other 49 results from the page are actually missing. The result that's displayed is't the first one that should be on the page, nor the last, it's from somewhere around the middle. Then the same for all subsequent pages.

Performing the same search without the profile, using the default view, everything displays as expected.

Any ideas what's up? Thanks!

Comment: Can you pls be specific about the fields in your profile. Someone else recently described the situation of only seeing 1 result, they had Group(s) and Tags fields set on the Profile - do you have either of those? I don't see them in your screenshot, but in his case they also did not show as columns

Comment: Ah! Apologies, I'd not managed to find anyone else with the issue. Yes, I did have Groups on the the profile. Taking it off has made the results display correctly. Obviously though, I had Groups on the profile because I really want it in the listing. Anything I can do to get it working? Or is this a bug that should be reported?

Comment: It is a bug/missing feature. It may be that having Groups show could be a really tricky addition and hence it has never been added - especially as I know of sites that would end up listing dozens and dozens of Groups for any one contact which would make the display pretty unmanageable. I believe we have customised Drupal views such that a search result can include list of all Groups including Smart Groups but that isn't a core civi solution

Answer (score 1):

It all worked perfectly in civi 5.8.2 prior to the upgrade.
It's a bug in 5.9.0, I am experiencing the same thing.
If I remove the "Default Contact Search Profile" everything is good.
I'm using civi on joomla.

Comment: also happening to us in 5.9.1 - search builder results are only showing one row - but able to export all results.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across something similar but it's not using the custom search profile. I've managed to recreate on the sandbox so I've raised an issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/679